# Increment Rows in ElseIf-Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy certain cells from a report to another worksheet.
There are two conditions and two rows to copy if one of the conditions applies.

As I am new to VBA, I don`t get the loop to work.
Main problem: How to increment the row that is to be searched and that is the paste target (B1->B2->B3..).
The loop is supposed to check and copy until the last row of the report.
So the

Can somebody help me how to code the loop or explain in an easy way how to do that? Thank you! :)

```
Sub CopyRow()

'Return to Sheets("CS15 Download"), Find Last Row and LastRow = that row
    Sheets("CS15").Select
    Range("A8").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    LastRow = ActiveCell.Row
    
    
Dim ObjDes As Variant
Const Lvl As Integer = 1

ObjDes = Range("Q1").Value

Range("B3").Select

If Range("B3").Value = Lvl Then

Sheets("Report").Range("B2").Value = Range("F3").Value
Sheets("Report").Range("C2").Value = Range("G3").Value
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select

ElseIf InStr(Range("G3").Value, ObjDes) > 0 Then

Sheets("Report").Range("B2").Value = Range("F3").Value
Sheets("Report").Range("C2").Value = Range("G3").Value
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
        
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: IF and ElseIf are not loops.  Loops Use `For`, `For Each`, `Do`, etc

Comment: @ScottCraner I know. I`d like to have the elseif statement within a loop.

Comment: You should be showing us your attempt to get a loop to work, and then we could show you where when and how it went wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Unfortunately, Idk how to approach the loop. I know it should be a Do While or Do Until loop around the ElseIf but that's it. This is why I described it. The online examples aren't really helping as they are very basic.

Comment: First step would be to replace the references to `ActiveCell` with references to a `Range` object variable that you `Set` instead of relying on `Select` and `Activate`. Then slash the `ElseIf` block in favor of an `Or` operator in the `If` conditional, and lose the `Else` block with the repeated `Select` calls; have a reference to that `ReportSheet`, and then write a small procedure that takes a `ByVal RowNumber As Long` parameter and invoke it inside the loop, passing in the row number; the procedure can then do `ReportSheet.Range("A" & RowNumber)` to work with the current row.